# jQuery - Timer will not delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game I have added a snowflake icon to freeze the time for 3 seconds. I have added this to the script

```
$(".character").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("freeze")) {
    $('#timer').delay(3000);
}
```

Any ideas why it will not work?

Here is a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/30/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missunderstood delay. You have to clear the countdown interval, and set timeout after which the countdown interval will be activated again

```
$(".character").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("freeze")) {
    window.clearInterval(countdown);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      countdown = window.setInterval(...)
    }, 3000);
}
```

and you'll have to name the function in order to do so

as for the [$.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) it's used to delay execution of jQuery animations

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks!! For some reason it is saying syntax error now for the (...) part. What is supposed to go there? @Darhazer

Comment: @Milo-J  Here is the working version of your program - http://jsfiddle.net/n5cz4/3/

Comment: Thanks!! What about if I wanted all the other divs to freeze for 3 seconds as well. I have tried to just add $('.character').stop(); but it doesnt work. How would you do that? @Darhazer